# Chromium Exception: closeDescriptionPopup is not defined

Tags: cordova, google-chrome

when  i debug Cordova APP , http://localhost:4433/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusS,the Chrom throw a error。

> eval code.js 中的 ，第 3 行    JavaScript Exception:
>   closeDescriptionPopup is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was using VSCODE to debug some html+javascript in chrome.

First VSCODE threw an error "*Exception has occurred: ReferenceError: exampleVariable is not defined*" because I had copied a line of code from inside a function (referencing a function argument) to before the function. So I just deleted that part of the code and then clicked the Restart button on the top of VSCODE to restart the debugger, but then it threw this error *"Exception has occurred: ReferenceError: closeDescriptionPopup is not defined"*.

I'm guessing the error has to do with VSCODE trying to close the error box it showed at the point in the code that is now deleted, but I'm not completely sure. Either way, it seems to start working correctly if I stop the debugger and then start it again (or stop the debugger, close and reopen VSCODE, and then start debugging again).